# What are the main attacks that can be done against a ZK Σ-protocol like Schnorr's identification scheme?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, attack

I heard about the "Chess Grandmaster Problem", Eavesdropping attacks and Man-in-the-middle.
Can they be applied in any way to a ZK protocol?
I'm not looking for long examples, just what are the main attacks and briefly how they work will do.
Thank you so much!

Comment: [Chess Grandmaster Problem and "Valid" Attacks on Zero-Knowledge Proofs of Identity](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/19681/18298)

Comment: That question isn't the same as this, even tho the title can make you think it is. In the one you linked, the guy asks clarification for a specific case of a specific attack in detail, in my question i'm asking what are all the different possible attacks against a ZK protocol in general, plus a little explanation. I said "I heard" because I have no idea what are the possible attacks, hence I can't provide links, otherwise I wouldn't have asked in the first place.